# Equal number of poles and zeros for square transfer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

In page 10 of [this document](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap27.pdf) (MIT Courseware on control) it is stated that *since the transfer function is square, there is an equal number of poles and zeros*. Does this hold and if so under which circumstances?

For example for the following system:

\begin{equation*}
G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+2)}  \left[\begin{array}{cc} s+1 & \frac{(s+1)}{(s+3)} \\               s+2 & \frac{(s+2)}{(s+5)}\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}

this does not hold as matlab can confirm:

```
>> G = 1/(s+2) * [s+1, (s+1)/(s+3); s+2, (s+2)/(s+5)];
>> pole(G)

ans =

   -2.0000
   -3.0000
   -2.0000
   -5.0000
   -2.0000

>> tzero(G)

ans =

   -1.0000
   -2.0000
   -2.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct form of that statement is that for an *invertible* transfer matrix the number of poles is equal to the number of zeroes.